# Can you modify a widget text field to filter the available options further in Django/Python?

Tags: python, django

I created a form with a field in my models called **employee_number**, which is tied to a separate model, called **Salesman**, which holds all the data with all the employee names, numbers, dept, etc.

Currently it works by only allowing submission of the form if the employee number entered is in **Salesman**. What I'm trying to do is also filter it further, so that only employees that are part of *team* "MM" and "OM" and whose *employee_status* is "A" are the only ones able to submit the form.

I saw a suggestion for someone with a similar problem where they said to add more constraints in the “attrs”, but I am not sure if it would work in this case too, as I am not too familiar with Python.

**forms.py**

```
class WarehouseForm(AppsModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeWorkAreaLog
        widgets = {
            'employee_number': ForeignKeyRawIdWidget(EmployeeWorkAreaLog._meta.get_field('employee_number').remote_field, site, attrs={'id':'employee_number_field'}),
        }
        fields = ('employee_number', 'work_area', 'station_number')
```

**models.py**

```
class EmployeeWorkAreaLog(TimeStampedModel, SoftDeleteModel, models.Model):
    employee_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    employee_number = models.ForeignKey(Salesman, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, help_text="Employee #", null=True, blank=False)
    work_area = models.ForeignKey(WorkArea, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False)
    station_number = models.ForeignKey(StationNumber, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.employee_number
```

**alldata/models.py**

```
class Salesman(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column='number', primary_key=True)
    team = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    employee_status = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True)
```